# Incrementing inside SAS proc sql

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to create a summary by group (represented by reporting_date) and it has repeating arguments and there should be a better way to do it than shown below:

```
proc sql;
create table summary_cmr as 
select distinct reporting_date, sum(cmr1) as bads_1, sum(cmr2) as bads_2, sum(cmr3) as bads_3, sum(cmr4) as bads_4
from have
group by 1;
quit;
```

How can I incrementally define the arguments of my sum function, without having to write all of them?

Comment: Why not just calculate the sums using SAS code instead or SQL code? Then you can use variable lists.

Answer (score 3):

Just use SAS code instead of SQL code.  Then you can use variable lists.

```
proc summary data=have nway;
  class reporting_date;
  output out=summary_cmr sum(cmr1-cmr4)=bads_1-bads_4 ;
run;
```

Comment: Nice use of variable range on the sum() output, never seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define them using a macro loop, and call the macro in PROC SQL

```
%MACRO SUMN(N) ;
  %LOCAL I ;
  %DO I = 1 %TO &N ;
    sum(cmr&I) as bads_&I,
  %END ;
  sum(0) as _EOL
%MEND ;

proc sql ;
  create table summary_cmr (drop=_EOL) as
  select reporting_date, %SUMN(10)
  from have
  group by 1 ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PROC MEANS to autoname variables:

```
proc means data=have missing noprint;
    class reporting_date;
    var cmr1-cmr3;
    output out=summary_cmr(where=(_TYPE_ > 0) )
        sum= / autoname;
run;
```

The variables will look as follows:

```
cmr1_Sum cmr2_Sum cmr3_Sum
...      ...      ...
```